# Shortest path with stopover in circular graph

Tags: graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I have a directed (weighted) circular graph like this:

[image: 1]

I would like to find the shortest path through a number of nodes with same start and end node. For example I would like to find the shortest path starting from node `0` going through node `3` and `4` and ending again at node `0`. It gets a little more complicated due to constraints e.g. node `4` should always be visited after node `3`. I visualized this constraint here:

[image: 2]

Is there any algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: But they don't take into account that there are stops in between. Let state another example: I would like to find a route from node 0 to node 0 with stops at node 3, 4 and 5 where node 5 is visited before node 3. The algorithms you propose only solve the problem to find a path between two nodes with no constraints. Or do I get this wrong?

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Reversing the path does not help in this case, as this would not be the shortest path in a circular graph. In case of the stated example the shortest path would be 0 - 6 - 5 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1 - 0 to visit nodes 3, 4, 5 with start and end being node 0.  Reversing would bring us to this path: 0 - 6 - 5 - 4 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 0.

Comment: This sounds more like the traveling salesman problem.

Comment: I wonder if it is really that hard or if it is possible to use the property that the graph is always circular somehow.

Comment: Doesn't any all-pairs shortest path algorithm solve this problem? Find the all-pairs shortest path and follow it for each consecutive pair the nodes to be visited. Am I missing something?

Comment: I would argue that all-pairs shortest path algo does not work with this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdAxm.png) and the stops 3, 4, 5, as the algo would suggest the path 0 - 5 - 3 - 4 - 0 (11 steps) but the shortest would be 0 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 0 (7 steps).